# Mobile push does not return feedback from push operations when sending a notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, react-native

[image]

Test done on ANDROID

The platform returns that the submission failed, but does not explain why it failed.

How do I get this feedback?

Comment: Open a support case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [running the MobilePush Detail Extract Report](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_run_the_mobilepush_detail_extract_report.htm&type=5&language=en_US).

There is a similarly named report in *Analytics Builder > Reports*, but it does not contain the `ServiceResponse` column - the values stored here can help you identify what's wrong at the moment based on this article:
[MobilePush Message Detail Extract Errors](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_mp_mobilepush_message_detail_extract_errors.htm&type=5&language=en_US)

| Status | ServiceResponse | Reasons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Failed | MismatchSenderId | Update your FCM key. |
| Failed | InvalidToken | This error occurs if some iOS users uninstall the app. However, if all of your iOS sends fail with this error, check that you uploaded the correct APNS certificate in Marketing Cloud. |
| Failed | NotRegistered | This error can indicate several different issues. A common reason this error occurs when sending to Android is that some users uninstalled the app. However, if all of your Android sends fail with this error, troubleshoot further on Salesforce Help. |
| Failed | Unregistered | This error can indicate several different issues. A common reason this error occurs when sending to iOS is that some users uninstalled the app. However, if all of your iOS sends fail with this error, troubleshoot further on Salesforce Help. |

If the data there is not helpful, create a support ticket.